# Slot of inherited class not recognized

Tags: c++, qt4, signals-slots

I'm trying to implement a custom class of `QTcpSocket` but it seems that my slots are not recognized at run time
I always get:

`Object::connect: No such slot QTcpSocket::timeoutSlot()`

Here is my code:

my header:

```
#ifndef CUSTOM_SOCKET_H
#define CUSTOM_SOCKET_H

#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QTimer>

class CustomSocket : public QTcpSocket {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomSocket(QObject* = 0);

private:
    QTimer *mAuthTimeout;

public slots:
    void timeoutSlot();

};
#endif
```

Implementation:

```
#include "customSocket.h"

CustomSocket::CustomSocket(QObject *aParent):QTcpSocket(aParent)
{
  mAuthTimeout = new QTimer();
  connect(mAuthTimeout, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeoutSlot()));
  mAuthTimeout->start(5000);

}

void CustomSocket::timeoutSlot(){
  std::cout << "Timeout " << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code quoted above.

The warning you get has 2 weird things about it;

- it complains about QTcpSocket::timeoutSlot().   We are not trying to connect to QTcpSocket, but to CustomSocket. The warning should mention this. If it doesn't then the Q_OBJECT macro may be missing.
- if I copy/paste the code and add it to an empty dir, add main(), then use qmake -project; qmake; make. It works just fine. No warning.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the QTcpSocket class, it's declared with the [Q_DISABLE_COPY](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#Q_DISABLE_COPY) macro. This possibly could be causing the errors you're seeing.

Whether or not that is the case, I think you'd be better off not inheriting from QTcpSocket, but instead creating an instance in your class: -

```
class CustomSocket : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    private:
        QTCPSocket* m_pSocket;    
};


CustomSocket::CustomSocket(QObject* parent)
    :QObject(parent)
{
    m_pSocket = new QTcpSocket(this);
}
```

You should then be Ok to connect to the QTcpSocket and use its signals and slots to communicate with it as normal.